# How to set vBarPolicy in ScrollPane ? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to set vertical scroll bar to be always visible.
But i want to do it, using only fxml. Currently I;m trying to do this, like this:

```
  <ScrollPane fitToHeight = "true" fitToWidth = "true">
     <vbarPolicy>
        <ScrollBarPolicy fx:constant = "ALWAYS" />
     </vbarPolicy>
     <LogView fx:id = "logViewLog" />
  </ScrollPane>
```

But I got this error:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: ScrollBarPolicy is not a valid type.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recommended Solution**

Set the `vbarPolicy` property directly to a string value of the [`ScrollBarPolicy`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.html) enumerated type: `vbarPolicy="ALWAYS"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<ScrollPane fitToHeight = "true" fitToWidth = "true" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS">
    <Label text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" minHeight="100" wrapText="true" alignment="TOP_LEFT"/>
</ScrollPane>
```

This will work for any enumerated type property.

See for instance in the example how `alignment="TOP_LEFT"`, similarly sets the value of the `Pos` enumerated type `alignment` property for the `Label`.

**Alternate Solution**

As Slaw noted in comments you can also do this in a verbose fashion using the `fx:constant` syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy?>

<ScrollPane fitToHeight = "true" fitToWidth = "true" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <vbarPolicy>
        <ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy fx:constant = "ALWAYS" />
    </vbarPolicy>
    <Label text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" minHeight="100" wrapText="true" alignment="TOP_LEFT"/>
</ScrollPane>
```

If you do this, ensure that you:

1. Define the `fx` namespace:

   ```
   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   ```
2. Import the `ScrollBarPolicy` type:

   ```
   <?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy?>
   ```

My preference would be to use the direct string conversion previously outlined rather than the `fx:constant` version.

Comment: Now it's work. But i have nested listView, inside scrollPane. And then listView getting filled I've got 2 scrollbars. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: That is a different question, that you should ask as a different question.  But, in general, don’t put a ListView in a ScrollPane.  For example,  use a VBox and/or Pagination control instead, or just a ListView.

Comment: @Rudolphine As for your original error, and if you wanted to keep the syntax in your question, you can use `<ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy fx:constant="ALWAYS"/>` since the policy enum is nested.